# edges produces right image, but check50 fails

Tags: cs50

I'm having an issue with the edges function of helpers.c

It generates the "right" image, but check50 fails all checks related to it

I tried creating a larger images with a black frame and then inserting the smaller image in the center of it, so when the program does the calculations for GX and GY it just uses that

check50 link for reference: "https://submit.cs50.io/check50/87cfe472a6c49c1f212f91ac346ea1bb532806eb"

[generated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwDMH.png)

my code:

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Create temporary_image array and fill it with values
    RGBTRIPLE temporary_image[height + 2][width + 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < height + 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width + 2; j++)
        {
            temporary_image[i][j].rgbtRed = 0;
            temporary_image[i][j].rgbtGreen = 0;
            temporary_image[i][j].rgbtBlue = 0;
        }
    }
    // Copy image to temporary array
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temporary_image[i + 2][j + 2].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            temporary_image[i + 2][j + 2].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            temporary_image[i + 2][j + 2].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }
    // Create gx and gy arrays
    const int gx[] = {-1, 0, 1, -2, 0, 2, -1, 0, 1};
    const int gy[] = {-1, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1};
    // Iterate over image array
    for (int i = 1; i < height + 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < width + 2; j++)
        {
            int rgx = 0, rgy = 0, ggx = 0, ggy = 0, bgx = 0, bgy = 0, t = 0;
            // Set pixel values
            for (int k = -1; k < 2; k++)
            {
                for (int l = -1; l < 2; l++)
                {
                    rgx = rgx + (gx[t] * image[i + k][j + l].rgbtRed);
                    rgy = rgy + (gy[t] * image[i + k][j + l].rgbtRed);
                    ggx = ggx + (gx[t] * image[i + k][j + l].rgbtGreen);
                    ggy = ggy + (gy[t] * image[i + k][j + l].rgbtGreen);
                    bgx = bgx + (gx[t] * image[i + k][j + l].rgbtBlue);
                    bgy = bgy + (gy[t] * image[i + k][j + l].rgbtBlue);
                    t++;
                }
            }
            image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = max_at_255(rgx, rgy);
            image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen = max_at_255(ggx, ggy);
            image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue = max_at_255(bgx, bgy);
        }
    }
    return;
}

int max_at_255(int gx, int gy)
{
    float g = sqrt(gx * gx + gy * gy);
    int result = round(g);
    if (result > 255)
    {
        return 255;
    }
    else
    {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried creating a larger images with a black frame and then inserting the smaller image in the center of it…
>
> ```
>             temporary_image[i + 2][j + 2].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
>             temporary_image[i + 2][j + 2].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
>             temporary_image[i + 2][j + 2].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
> ```

In order for *inserting the smaller image in the center*, the indexing must be `temporary_image[i+1][j+1]`; with `+2`, `image` gets placed in the lower right of the larger image, with no *frame* below and to the right.